# Did I accidentally update all my fields on the production database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran the following query.

```
update Finished_goods_adjustment_detail
set Actual_Price_Per_Piece = 5.90
Select * 
from 
--Finished_Goods_Adjustment F left join 
Finished_goods_adjustment_detail fd 
--on f.Company_Code=fd.Company_Code and f.Division_Code =fd.Division_Code and f.Ticket_Number = fd.Ticket_Number
Where Fd.Ticket_Number = '10063677' and fd.Company_Code ='01' and fd.Division_Code ='006'
```

I meant to comment out the

```
Select * 
from
```

but I forgot.

I alternate between commenting out the select * part and the update set part to check what the changes I made were.

I accidentally ran the query with the select * part but the where clause was included.

Now it seems that the Actual_Price_Per_Piece field has become 5.90 for all my rows in the Finished_goods_adjustment_detail table.

I'm not sure if thats is how it was before but I doubt it. Would running that above query with the select * not commenting cause that to happen? even when it says a specific ticket number in where? Please help.

It said

(445217 rows affected)

and under it it said

(8 rows affected) (the correct amount)

in the messages tab.

Comment: Sorry, but all records were updated. the `select *` is parsed as starting a new sql command, so the `UPDATE` ran without any `WHERE` clause. Hopefully you may have backups somewhere?

Comment: Best thing to do is OWN UP TO IT, and talk to your manager and/or DBA.

Comment: The good news about Execution Risk, is that it tends to happen only once.

Comment: Definitely talk to Manager/DBA...they may have had to recover from something like this in past and can help. Having a good DBA could open up options besides just backup/restore or manually reloading from outside source, such as transaction log rollback: http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/

Comment: And talk to your manager ASAP. Don't wait until tomorrow. Keep him/her posted right away. And also show you have a plan to recover from this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by Jason W pretty much covers it. However, I would like to add a bit of advice on how to avoid such situations in the future (you know, we all had these moments in our lives, myself included).

Specifically, by slightly tweaking your coding style you can introduce a reliable fail-safe so that update wouldn't work. All you need to do is reference the updated table by its alias, not by its name:

```
update fd
set Actual_Price_Per_Piece = 5.90
Select * 
from 
Finished_goods_adjustment_detail fd 
Where Fd.Ticket_Number = '10063677' and fd.Company_Code ='01' and fd.Division_Code ='006'
```

The `fd` alias is defined in the `FROM` clause, and (hopefully) an object with this name doesn't exist in the database. This way, the `update` will break with "Object not found" error, and the `select` will run as usual (or not run at all, depending on `XACT_ABORT` connection option and presence of `Try/Catch`, just to name a few).

Simple, really.

P.S. By the way, the same approach works with `delete` statements, too. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, that full query would have caused SQL to execute 2 commands:

1. The `update` query without any `where` clause
2. The `select` query with the `where` clause

This is why you saw the 2 result set counts. The 445217 would have been the `update`, and the 8 is just the `select`.

To restore the data, hopefully you have a recent backup that you can restore to separate location so you can update just this table (especially if you have point-in-time recovery available).

For future development, if you are testing this on a lower environment, but want to test your joins, you can rework your comments so that you prevent this PRD risk:

```
update Finished_goods_adjustment_detail
set Actual_Price_Per_Piece = 5.90
-- Select *  from 
--Finished_Goods_Adjustment F left join 
Finished_goods_adjustment_detail fd 
--on f.Company_Code=fd.Company_Code and f.Division_Code =fd.Division_Code and f.Ticket_Number = fd.Ticket_Number
Where Fd.Ticket_Number = '10063677' and fd.Company_Code ='01' and fd.Division_Code ='006'
```

Now you can just highlight everything from the `SELECT *` to get the results with just the `SELECT`, or run the whole query to get the `UPDATE`. Either way, you prevent accidentally running the `SELECT` or `UPDATE` without proper joins or `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Another "failsafe" move is to preface `update` and/or `delete` statements with `BEGIN TRANS`. This will open a transaction and execute your query without committing any changes to the underlying table. If your query returns `(waaay too many rows affected`, just type and execute `ROLLBACK`, and no harm done. The transaction will be rolled back. If you get your expected `(reasonable number of rows affected)`, type and execute `COMMIT`, and your changes will take affect then, and only then. Be sure that you do one or the other, though, and don't leave uncommitted transactions laying around.

Comment: Continuing from where @EricBrandt stopped: You might want to make it a habit. Write the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` first. Next line `ROLLBACK`. Third line `COMMIT`. Now insert some blank lines before `ROLLBACK` and start experimenting with your code in that guarded space. Following Jason W's hints about carefully placed comments as well. If you now run (accidentally) the whole batch instead of just a particular statement, the `ROLLBACK` will fix it right away. STILL be careful though, e.g., DDL statements and `TRUNCATE TABLE` are not stopped by this technique…

Comment: @Abecee, are you ready to bet a beer on that `TRUNCATE` assertion? :)

Comment: @Abecee, unlike some other DBMS products, SQL Server does allow one to execute most DDL (including `TRUNCATE`) in a transaction.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Thanks for the heads-up! (Having had more of an Oracle exposure - my reading of TSQL docs was apparently skewed.) Seems to make such guarded space even more helpful.